# Should I use organization-wide calendars using SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, calendar, outlook

**Problem**
Our company needs a solution to manage several organization-wide calendars. We need to control permissions on these calendars based on individual users or groups of users. Permissions are relatively simple and match the SharePoint Owner / Member / Viewer default groups.

**Potential Solutions / Research**
After reviewing potential solutions [here](https://sharepointmaven.com/a-review-of-all-the-calendar-options-in-sharepoint-and-office-365/), it seems like SharePoint calendars would be a good fit for what we are trying to do.

The one limitation being that users have to manually connect SharePoint calendars to their Outlook.  We've used SharePoint calendars before and found that users do not use them unless they can update/view them in Outlook.

I'd like to roll these calendars out to groups of user's automatically instead of training them to use "Connect to Outlook".  I've done some initial research and found most of the articles on this topic are from 2016 or earlier.  The latest post I found was on SpiceWorks [here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2254523-push-a-sharepoint-calendar-via-gpo).

**Question**
I wanted to make sure I'm using the right tool for the right job.  Are there better ways to maintain organization-wide calendars with custom permissions?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure there is an easy option for you to make all users connect to outlook automatically in SharePoint Online. And if you make the connection once, the calendar will always be in the outlook calendar, so have a consider on making users to do it.

And I am not sure why Office 365 group calendar is not your final choice. If you are worrying about the permission issue, maybe you can have a check on [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/office365-group-set-calendar-to-be-read-only-for/ebaa7a58-7bd0-4b47-9695-5a6445583401). You shall be able to set members read-only. And of course the permission settings does not work as well as SharePoint. However once the user is added to the group, the group calendar will show up in the outlook.

I will suggest you to have a try on both of them and find the one fits you better.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  We had investigated Office 365 groups but stopped because they create a shared mailbox, OneNote, OneDrive, etc.  We also moved away from Office 365 groups due to the permission challenge. The solution you provided would work but we would need to remember to re-run the script for any new employees. I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: @BrianBellBri, thanks for the update. If that is your scenario, I guess SharePoint Calendar is you best option. And per my knowledge, MS treat Gropu Calendar as the successor of SharePoint Calendar, so it will not be modernized.  BTW the script I provide works for group, so i think there is no need to re-run it.